# which one runs first: new thread or main thread?

Tags: java, scheduler

I ran this code and got this result:

```
//back in main
//directly from the runnable
//top of the stack
```

Shouldn't I get `top of the stack` as my first result?

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("directly from the runnable");
        go();
    }
    public void go() {
        doMore();
    }
    public void doMore() {
        System.out.println("top of the stack");
    }
}

public class ThreadTester{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable threadJob = new MyRunnable();
        Thread myThread = new Thread(threadJob);

        myThread.start();

        System.out.println("back in main");
    }

}
```

Comment: They run concurrently.  That's the whole point.

Comment: I do not see how `top of the stack` can possibly be the 1st message. Care to explain?

Comment: @JeffGohlke You are right Jeff, but I saw different results on the book I'm reading ("top of stack" was its first result) and thought maybe it has some order ...

Comment: Not with the code you posted. [Elliott Frisch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24472175/2055998) explained it quite clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Threads dont have a specific order, it can be either way. The JVM is the one that decides that and it can give different results every time.

Comment: The JVM can only *try* to enforce an order - ultimately it's the operating system deciding which thread comes first.

Answer (score 3):

Your runnable() or your main() may start first, but this

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("directly from the runnable");
    go();
}
```

Means that "directly from the runnable" will always print before "top of the stack". If you want that reversed,

```
public void run() {
    go();
    System.out.println("directly from the runnable");
}
```